# Timeframe for debian to package new rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, debian

On average, how long does it take for Debian to package new versions of rubygem packages (assume the package doesn't have C code) into their package system? Is it more like weeks, months or years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vast majority of gems don't make it into Debian's package repository at all.

There is a Ruby packaging team that is moderately active. My unscientific estimate is that the gems that do make it in are generally updated within a couple of week to a couple of months.

This is unstable of course, it takes a bit longer for the new packages to filter up to testing.